# weblogic Grails app. context lost on redirect

Tags: grails, redirect, intellij-idea, weblogic, contextpath

I have upgraded a Grails application from **1.3.7** to **2.2.3** (and I tried **2.2.4**).  It used to work fine when deployed to our Weblogic server. Now, whenever a "redirect(....)" is encountered  in a controller the page redirects but the context root is lost so the page is not found.

For example with a context root of `/myapp` as soon as a redirect is encountered within a controller, regardless of redirecting within the same controller or to a different controller, the result loses the context root. So I get

```
/controller/action
```

instead of

```
/myapp/controller/action
```

The application works fine in my local development environment using Intellij and Tomcat.

Comment: Can you add an exact copy of `Config.groovy` of the app? Wanted to make sure that the context root is not tampered/overridden for production environment and is same as that of other environments.

Comment: The relevant lines from the Config.groovy would be: grails.app.context = "QDisk" .  I have commented out all grails.serverURL but that made no difference.  I have also tried putting the context in the weblogic.xml file but that didn't help. The fact that normal submits and links and everything else works means it knows what the context root is.